# How to get the middle of the screen for API>=19

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-screen

The button should move to the middle of the screen when clicked. But every time I get different position of button in different devices. And I don't know how can I fix it.
This code what I use:

```
 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
                float middleScreen = metrics.xdpi;
final TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -middleScreen, 0, 0);
                animation.setDuration(3000);
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
 buttonToNextView.setAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what `DisplayMetrics.xdpi` gave us is the `exact physical pixels per inch of the screen in the X dimension` which is not the number of pixels on the x-axis.

So, we should use half of `widthPixels` and `heightPixels` (based on screen orientation) to achieve the middle of the screen on the x-axis.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);

boolean isDisplayPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
float middleScreen = isDisplayPortrait ? metrics.widthPixels / 2 : metrics.heightPixels / 2;

final TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -middleScreen, 0, 0);
animation.setDuration(3000);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
buttonToNextView.setAnimation(animation);
```

Notice that to place the button exactly at the middle of the screen, you need to subtract half of its width from the `middleScreen` value.

Comment: thank you for your advice. I think the main problem is that I didn't substract half of button from the middleScreen value.